# Code generated by Java synchronized function

Tags: java, synchronization

I don't really see the difference of execution between

```
public void foo_fct( Table Tbl, Account act)
{
  synchronized(Tbl) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and this :

```
public void foo_fct( Table Tbl, Account act)
{
  synchronized(act) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I mean, under the hood, the JVM must use lock() and unlock() I guess?
So whatever it happens (act or Tbl) I will be locking in the same way no ?

**update**
Ok, I understand now with your help and Java doc :

*"...Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it..."*

and *"synchronized statements..."*

Comment: What do you think `synchronized` does?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html should be a place to start for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If table and accounts are organized in fixed exclusive pairs meaning no foo_fct on a table x will be called with different account instances by different concurrent threads (and vice versa) and there no other parts of the code that make other synchronized operations on tables or accounts in your program concurrently then both ways to lock are equivalent.

Otherwise both approaches would be different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference, since you never know which other threads are using `sychronized` on the `Table` or the `Account`.

Ask yourself the question- are you trying to prevent other mutable operations on the `Table` or the `Account` for the duration of execution of the `sychronized` block in `foo_fct` method?

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized(var)` block will make difference based on the *...* block that you omitted, i.e. on which variable you already need to synchronize concurrent threads access.